# Get the scroll position in a div

Tags: javascript, scroll

This must be something trivial I am missing, I really can't figure it out:

I am gazing here for quite a long time: [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop)

I am playing here for quite a long time: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HR3M4/)

And I am about to bring some human sacrifice to get the answer **why the hell is scrollTop always zero**?

**HTML**

```
  <div style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: scroll">
    <div id="x" style="height: 100px; background: #EEE;"></div>
    <div style="height: 500px"></div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
  var x = document.getElementById("x");
  x.parentNode.onscroll = function() { console.log(x.scrollTop); }
```

Please don't jQuery me.

Comment: What part of the spec you don't understand: "`The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that the content of an element is scrolled upward.`"? You don't have scrollable content in `#x`...

Comment: Yes, of course - now I see it. I guess I have been staring on it for too long. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your jsFiddle and it shows the scroll position correctly. It is an old answer and scroll behavior support was not 100% then and it is still work in progress, see [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using wrong element to get topScroll [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HR3M4/1/)
it should be `x.parentNode.scrollTop` instead of `x.scrollTop`

```
  var x = document.getElementById("x");
     x.parentNode.onscroll = function() { console.log(x.parentNode.scrollTop);
  }
```